# How to be able to toggle true/false each single toggle box in editor window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that i loop over the objects array. objects is array of selection gameobjects.

When i loop over it and create the toggles then when i check/uncheck a single toggle box it's checking/unchecking all the toggles.  how can i make that it will toggle only single ?

The one i checked i want only him to be enabled true/false.

The loop part :

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
                {
                    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 50;
    
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                    {
                        GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.MaxWidth(300.0f), GUILayout.MinWidth(300.0f) };
                        objects[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(), objects[i], typeof(GameObject), true, options);
                        EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 112;
                        include1 = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", include1, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    
                EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
            }
```

The include1 are the toggles i want to be able to enable true/false individual.

The rest of the code :

```
public void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(10);
        childrenPrefix = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Rename prefix", childrenPrefix);
        startIndex = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Start index", startIndex);
        includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);

        if (objects.Length == 0)
        {
            showPosition = false;
        }
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(true, 16f, EditorStyles.foldout);
        Rect foldRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp && foldRect.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
        {
            showPosition = !showPosition;
            GUI.changed = true;
            Event.current.Use();
        }

        showPosition = EditorGUI.Foldout(foldRect, showPosition, "Objects");
        GUILayout.Space(2);

        if (showPosition)
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

            scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 50;

                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.MaxWidth(300.0f), GUILayout.MinWidth(300.0f) };
                    objects[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(), objects[i], typeof(GameObject), true, options);
                    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 112;
                    include1 = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", include1, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }

        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Rename Objects"))
        {

        }

        Repaint();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your include1 an array of bool so each item has its own value